# Why does sendSignInLinkToEmail(email, settings) not check whether the given email exists?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I don't understand, why `firebase.auth().sendSignInLinkToEmail(email, settings)` sends a login email to an email address which has not been registered yet.

Moreover, when I then click the link, which opens the site where I check the email with `firebase.auth().signInWithEmailLink(email, signInEmailLink)`, the email gets *registered* and the user is logged in!

I think that's curios, because I've build a separate registration process.

I would expect, that I get an error when I call `firebase.auth().sendSignInLinkToEmail(email, settings)` with an unregistered email.

What am I doing wrong?

That's my code for sending the email and signing in when user clicked the link.

```
async login(email) {
    try {
        const settings = {
            handleCodeInApp: true,
            url: encodeURI(`${location.protocol}//${location.host}/#!/user/verifizieren`),
        };
        await firebase.auth().sendSignInLinkToEmail(email, settings);
        window.localStorage.setItem(storageKeyEmail, email);
    } catch(error) {
        console.error(error);
        throw error;
    }
},

async verify(email, link) {
    const signInEmailLink = link || window.location.href;
    if(!firebase.auth().isSignInWithEmailLink(signInEmailLink)) {
        return Promise.reject('auth/link-invalid');
    }
    try {
        await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailLink(email, signInEmailLink);
        firebase.auth().currentUser.reload();
        firebase.auth().currentUser.getIdToken(true);
        window.localStorage.removeItem(storageKeyEmail);
    } catch(error) {
        console.error(error);
        throw error;
    }
},
```

Comment: If a Firebase Auth API isn't working the way you expect, and you have questions for the authors, please file a bug report on GitHub.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk

Comment: Same question now here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/2332

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sign in with email link is designed to also work for new email accounts. The accounts are not required to already exist.
If you want to block the email sending, you can check if the account exists before hand:

```
firebase.auth().fetchSignInMethodsForEmail(email).then((signInMethods) => {
  if (signInMethods.length === 0) {
    // New user.
  } else {
    // Existing user.
  }
});
```

However, the above is only client side enforced and thus can be bypassed by the user by calling the REST API.

Comment: But isn't that a design problem? Because then it's not possible to separate the login process from registration process - where I ask for some more data then just the email.

Comment: I'm really interested in understanding why "Sign in with email" was designed this way. I just see that enabling this option makes every extra registration process vulnerable. Doesn't it?

Comment: How is this vulnerable? Most applications use it this way. Sign in with email link can be used for sign up by many applications. Granted there is a good use case for disabling sign up with this process. You should file a feature request for that.

Comment: "vulnerable" may be the wrong word, but your answer sounds like you know what I meant. Thanks for you answer anyways! I'll write a FR on github.

Comment: I think because it's straightforward to verify an existing user with a cloud function using getUserByEmail or the client side solution above, this is an elegant solution with minimal methods without sacrificing functionality.